# How to automate the command line for the input() in python

Tags: python-3.x, input, automated-tests

I am new to python and I am using idle 3.7.4. I want to automate command line to input() in python.

For example:

a = input("Please enter your name : ")

I want to add my name without manually typing it. I read about run() method under subprocess module, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Any helps are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [mock library](https://pypi.org/project/mock/) to do this with the builtins. For example, like this:

```py
import mock
import builtins
def input_test():
    ans = input("Please input your name :")
    return f"your name is {ans}"

def test_input():
    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda _: "okay"):
        assert input_test() == 'your name is okay'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want something like it should answer by itself to the command line. If the name is "okay", then I do not want to manually enter it. Is it possible?

Comment: This doesnt require you to manually enter it?

Comment: I don't want to manually enter it.